# Server error while posting value using volley

Tags: android-volley, server-error

can't find what is wrong with my code , but it is giving server error ,i have tried is many way , but still not working , if i could find the bug , maybe i could solve it

```
    final String username=etUserName.getText().toString();
    final String password=etPass.getText().toString();
    String url = "http://192.168.3.63/survey/api/users";
    JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<>();
            // the POST parameters:
            params.put("Name",username);
            params.put("Password",password);
            return params;
        }
    };
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(postRequest);
```

Comment: are you getting toast message from Response.Listener() or Response.ErrorListener()?

Comment: i am getting toast error message as com.volley.ServerError